# Libraries for calculating options strategy-based margin

Tags: options, margin

Hopefully, this is an acceptable question in this forum, even if it isn't analytically focused.

As part of an effort to analyse the effect of different option trade structures on a portfolio, I need to determine the margin requirements for different trades. Normally I would just build the margin calculation for the specific strategy I am using. In this case, the system needs to be able to handle more complex and possibly non-traditional option trade structures.

I am looking for a programming library that could be given the appropriate trade information and produce the margin/cost requirements for the trade based on the CBOE Strategy-Based Margin Rules.

[CBOE Margin Manual](http://www.cboe.com/framed/pdfframed.aspx?content=/learncenter/pdf/margin2-00.pdf&section=SECT_MINI_SITE&title=CBOE%20Margin%20Manual)

I could work with a library written in R, MATLAB, .NET, Java, Javascript or C++. A .NET library would be ideal but I could work with almost anything, especially if it was open source.

Comment: Ok, getting little response. As a side question is anyone interested in collaborating on one?

Comment: Does the [Margin calculator](http://www.cboe.com/tradtool/mcalc/default.aspx) at the same CBOE site do what you need?

Comment: Also an [abandoned project](https://github.com/vab/margincalc) at GitHub

Comment: @GodLovesATrier The CBOE site tool is very limited and only calculates the margin for a specific trade structure you choose. It also has no way of handling non-traditional trades. I need something that I can give the trade components (legs) and it determines the type of margin aplicable. The CBOE online tool is also server side and could not be used as a library in a project. I wish the project you pointed to actually amounted to something.  Thanks

Comment: Ok, looks like no obvious answers even with a bounty. Is anyone interested in contributing to a .NET (C#) open source project on Github to create this?